# Object is not recognized in two different versions Java swing application using UFT

Tags: swing, qtp, hp-uft

I am automating a Java swing application. There is a update in AUT. Object is recognized in all previous versions of AUT, but after the update objects are not recognized.

When I checked the previous version of AUT, UFT is able to recognize the objects.

I checked with developers and they say, there is no change in object properties.What could be the possible reasons for this behavior. I have enabled Java addin. Could it be a Add in issue ?

Comment: Can you spy the object and check the properties if you see an change? Check also the parent object(s)- do a highlight from OR and check if parent object is highlighted.

Comment: There is a java update in AUT from 1.7 to 1.8, so I was Using UFT 12.00 which does not support Java 1.8, so Updated to UFT 12.02 which supports java 1.8. Now able to resolve the issue . Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks for the update. May be add it as the answer might help others in future.

Comment: We also faced the same issue when using UFT 11.x .. then upgraded to newer UFT version and the issue was resolved.. never knew it was due to Java 8 update.